# error C2678: binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'volatile A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I've programmed in C++ before, but it's been several years. I'm new to C++11 and I'm having trouble with the following.

My class is more complicated than just storing "twice the value given in the constructor", but for the sake of simplicity this example just multiplies the constructor input by 2. The class must implicitly convert to & from an `int`, thus the `operator int()`, `operator=(const int)`, and constructor that takes an `int`.

Everything works fine unless an instance of my class is defined as `volatile`. When I subsequently try to do operations with the volatile instance, Visual Studio complains:

```
#include <iostream

class A
{
private:
   int _i;
public:
   A() = default;
   constexpr A(const int i) : _i(i*2) {}
   constexpr operator int() const { return _i/2; }
   A& operator=(const int i) { _i = i*2; return *this; }
};

//A va; // <---- this works (though I need it to be 'volatile')
volatile A va; // <--- this gives error C2678: binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'volatile A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

int main()
{
   int j;
   j = va + 12; // <--- Here's where the error occurs
   std::cout << "j = " << j << std::endl;
}
```

Seeing that the error suggests that there's "no acceptable conversion", I tried adding to the class a copy constructor that takes a `volatile` other, but that didn't fix the problem:

```
   constexpr A(volatile const A& other) : _i(other._i) {}
```

I can "fix" it by casting away the `volatile`...

```
   j = (A)va + 12;
```

...but that solution doesn't work for me because my class is actually part of a simulator environment that's trying to simulate embedded hardware and run the embedded code within the simulation environment. My class has to act as a stand-in for hardware registers, and I can't (or don't want to) cast away `volatile` in the statement `j = va + 12;` because that line is part of the embedded firmware itself. Is there some conversion operator or method I can add to my `class A` to make the statement `j = va + 12;` work without modification?

Comment: How in the world does this question deserve an unexplained downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the `volatile` in the wrong place.

In order to perform the addition in `j = va + 12`, `va` needs to be converted to an `int` since there isn't an `operator+` defined within `A`.  The existing conversion operator is marked `const`, which the compiler will not use to convert a `volatile` object.

The solution is to add an additional `operator int` to your class that supports conversion of volatile objects:

```
constexpr operator int() volatile { return _i/2; }
```

You'll need both the existing `const` one and this one.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I tried it exactly as you wrote (`constexpr operator int() volatile {...}`) but Visual Studio warned: `warning C4814: 'A::operator int': in C++14 'constexpr' will not imply 'const'; consider explicitly specifying 'const'`. But if I wrote it as `constexpr operator int() const volatile {...}` there was no warning. So would that one operator method, with both `const` and `volatile`, suit all purposes (and not require a separate `const` operator)?

Comment: @phonetagger I compiled this with VS17 and didn't get that warning.  Specifying both `const volatile` doesn't generate any warnings for either a `const int va` or `volatile int va`, so that seems like it would work.