# How to define conversion operator to permit built-in operator += to work for adding two classes

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I'm defining classes as stand-ins for hardware registers in a Windows PC-based simulation environment for embedded code. To work seamlessly and appear to the embedded firmware code as if they were hardware registers, the classes have to implicitly convert to/from their appropriate standard fixed-width types (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and their signed counterparts), based on the size & type of the hardware register.

The classes work beautifully (with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49090641/1245420) SO answer) except that the compiler can't figure out that it needs to do the implicit conversion to handle `+=` operations when two such types are combined in a `+=` operation:

```
#include <iostream>

class REG16
{
private:
   uint16_t _i;
public:
   REG16() = default;
   constexpr REG16(const unsigned int i) : _i((uint16_t)i * 2) {}
   constexpr operator uint16_t() const { return _i / 2; }
   REG16& operator=(const unsigned int i) { _i = (uint16_t)i * 2; }
};

class REG32
{
private:
   uint32_t _i;
public:
   REG32() = default;
   constexpr REG32(const uint32_t i) : _i(i * 2) {}
   constexpr operator uint32_t() const { return _i / 2; }
   REG32& operator=(const uint32_t i) { _i = i * 2; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
   REG16 a(12);
   REG32 b(12);
   uint32_t c;
   REG32 d;

   // Works great: 'a' is implicitly converted to a uint16_t, then added to 'c':
   c = 0;
   c += a;
   std::cout << "c = 0; c += a;     result:   c = " << c << std::endl;

   // Works great: 'b' is implicitly converted to a uint32_t, then added to 'c':
   c = 0;
   c += b;
   std::cout << "c = 0; c += b;     result:   c = " << c << std::endl;

   // Works great: 'b' and 'd' are both implicitly converted to uint32_t's,
   // then added together as uint32_t's, and assigned back to 'd' with the
   // REG32::operator=() asignment operator:
   d = 0;
   d = d + b;
   std::cout << "d = 0; d += b;     result:   d = " << d << std::endl;

   // Does not work:
   // error C2676: binary '+=': 'REG32' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
   d = 0;
   d += b; // <------ line with the error
   std::cout << "d = 0; d += b;     result:   d = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

As demonstrated above, instead of `d += b;` I could just do `d = d + b;` but the whole purpose of these classes is to operate the same as a real hardware register would, one that's defined as a `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc. for the simulation & testing environment. I don't want to impose strange restrictions on the embedded firmware just to be able to run in the simulation environment.

Is there something I can change or add to my classes to enable the compiler to do the appropriate implicit conversions to enable use of the built-in `operator+=` that's built-in for the standard types? I'd like to avoid having to define my own `operator+=` methods for combinations of these classes because that's a lot of permutations to have to handle; I'd rather the compiler's implicit conversions do the work for me.

Comment: Besides what you're asking about, gcc also complains about `error: expression ‘((const volatile REG16*)this)->REG16::_i’ has side-effects` -- pointing to your `constexpr operartor uint32_t()` that, somehow, must also be `volatile`. Now, back to the main topic: since youobviously understand how classes can define custom operators, what exactly stops you from defining the `+=` operator?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Yes, I could define the `+=` operator. But then I'd probably find that I also have to define the `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `%=`, `&=`, `|=`, and `^=` operators. And there are (at this point) six such classes, and that's a lot of operator methods to define to handle all combinations. If there was a way to make the compiler use implicit conversions for these so it can use the built-in operators for the built-in types, that would be highly preferable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I also edited my question to remove the `volatile` keyword, as that's a separate issue from this question.

Comment: I haven't as yet thought of a way to do it. Wheels still turning. I question the use of `volatile`. That is only for accessing memory mapped hardware.

Comment: There's a possible narrowing cast when going from `int` to `uint16_t` or `unint32_t` in the constructors.

Comment: @JiveDadson - I chose to make the inputs to the 16-bit classes be 'int' (or 'unsigned int') because if I don't do that, I get all sorts of those "narrowing" errors when the (already written and running for years) firmware code assigns constants to those objects. By making the constructor & `operator=()` args be int, I avoid those errors. If you know of a better way (that doesn't involve changing the already-written firmware that I'm trying to make run in simulation), please let me know.

Comment: You could hush the warnings like so ... `constexpr REG16(const unsigned int i) : _i(static_cast<uint16_t>(i) * 2) {}`  etc...

Comment: @JiveDadson - Ahhh. Yes. The "i * 2" stuff in my example is bogus. My real classes do more than that (in fact they don't really do "i * 2"). They way my ***real*** classes work avoids that in the first place without the casting. But the reason I didn't see the warnings in my SO test project is because somehow the default warning level is turned down. When I turned it up to /W4 I saw it. So I added a couple casts in the posted code to get rid of those. If you have any ideas on how I might accomplish what I'm asking about, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166177/discussion-between-jive-dadson-and-phonetagger).

Comment: Why is  REG32 b(12); and REG32 d; ? Does it help if you make them the same? I.e. d(12); or b;

Comment: Yes you do have to explicitly define the `+=`, `*=` and all other operators. `C++` does not have any kind of an "easy" button to define all operator overloads for custom classes, instantly. You have to do all the hard work.

Comment: @Marichyasana - I wanted `b` to have an initial value of 12, so I used the parameterized constructor. With `d` I didn't need it to have a value yet (at the point I defined it, near the top of `main()`), so I used the default constructor. Since I eventually wanted it to have the value `0`, I could have defined it with `REG32 d(0);` either at the top of `main()` or even down where I first use it (and omit the first `d = 0;` line), but I wanted to show all of the variables I'm using together at the top of `main()`. I do not do that out of habit, but I chose to do it this time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I hear you. But the "easy" button has worked so far, for a whole lot of stuff. I don't have to overload `operator+`, `operator-`, `operator*`, or `operator/`, as the `operator uint16_t` and `operator uint32_t` conversion operators result in implicit conversion so the compiler just uses the built-in math operators. I was hoping that strategy would work for all operators, but it seems it doesn't. I was hoping some small tweak would make it work for `+=`, `-=`, etc. as well as it does for `+`, `-`, etc.

Comment: First there's no type suitable for `+=` that your class can convert to. `+=` needs a reference on the left side, which your class cannot provide. There's also no automatic interpretation of += as + followed by an assignment. Second, the implicit conversion leads to the result of + etc being the built-in type, so it isn't quite clear why you need a class in the first place.

Comment: Take another look at the answer I put up. It won't require writing much boiler-plate - only operators that return a reference to the class, like `+=`, `<<=`, etc.. --  AND, it's reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with the problem about 25 years ago. Tonight I searched for a template that I wrote back then to help with such things. I would give it to you, but I regret that it's probably lost. It was a mix-in, something vaguely like the one below. I think it at least solves the proliferation-of-operator-signatures problem.

**Thanks** to Ben Voigt for suggesting CRTP.

**Thanks** to Jens for improving the code.

**Thanks** to  Mike Kinghan for the regression testing.

```
#include <cstdint>
using std::uint32_t;
using std::uint16_t;

template<typename Derived, typename Value_t>
class number {
public:

    constexpr number(Value_t& x) : i(x) {}

    template<class R>
    Derived&
        operator+= (const R& r) {
        i += static_cast<Value_t>(r); return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
    // ... and scads of other operators that I slavishly typed out.
protected:
    ~number() {} // to prevent slicing
private:
    Value_t & i;
};


class REG16: public number<REG16, uint16_t>
{
private:
    uint16_t _i;
    using Num = number<REG16, uint16_t>;
public:
    REG16() : Num(_i) {}
    constexpr REG16(const unsigned int i) : _i(i), Num(_i) {}
    constexpr operator uint16_t() const { return _i; }
    REG16& operator=(const unsigned int i) { _i = i; }
};

class REG32 : public number<REG32, uint32_t>
{
private:
    uint32_t _i;
    using Num = number<REG32, uint32_t>;
public:
    REG32() : Num(_i) {}
    constexpr REG32(const uint32_t i) : _i(i), Num(_i) {}
    constexpr operator uint32_t() const { return _i; }
    REG32& operator=(const uint32_t i) { _i = i; return *this; }
};
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    REG16 a(12);
    REG32 b(12);
    uint32_t c;
    REG32 d;

    // Works great: 'a' is implicitly converted to a uint16_t, then added to 'c':
    c = 0;
    c += a;
    std::cout << "c = 0; c += a;     result:   c = " << c << std::endl;

    // Works great: 'b' is implicitly converted to a uint32_t, then added to 'c':
    c = 0;
    c += b;
    std::cout << "c = 0; c += b;     result:   c = " << c << std::endl;

    // Works great: 'b' and 'd' are both implicitly converted to uint32_t's,
    // then added together as uint32_t's, and assigned back to 'd' with the
    // REG32::operator=() asignment operator:
    d = 0;
    d = d + b;
    std::cout << "d = 0; d += b;     result:   d = " << d << std::endl;

    // DID NOT WORK
    // error C2676: binary '+=': 'REG32' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
    d = 0;
    d += b; // <------ line that had the error
    std::cout << "d = 0; d += b;     result:   d = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

---

UPDATE by phonetagger:

This is what I actually ended up using as the base class for every `REG` class:

```
// numericCompoundAssignmentBase is a template base class for use with types that implement numeric behavior
template<typename DT, typename NT> // DerivedType, NativeType (native types: uint8_t, uint16_t, etc.)
struct numericCompoundAssignmentBase
{
   NT  operator++ (int) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this); NT x(dt); dt = x + 1;  return x; } // postfix ++
   NT  operator-- (int) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this); NT x(dt); dt = x - 1;  return x; } // postfix --
   DT& operator++ ()    { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this); NT x(dt); dt = x + 1;  return dt; } // prefix --
   DT& operator-- ()    { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this); NT x(dt); dt = x - 1;  return dt; } // prefix --
   DT& operator+= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt + r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator-= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt - r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator*= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt * r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator/= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt / r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator%= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt % r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator&= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt & r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator|= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt | r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator^= (const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt ^ r;  return dt; }
   DT& operator<<=(const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt << r; return dt; }
   DT& operator>>=(const NT& r) { DT& dt = static_cast<DT&>(*this);  dt = dt >> r; return dt; }
   private: numericCompoundAssignmentBase() = default; friend DT; // ensures the correct 'DT' was specified
};
```

Comment: Might want CRTP to allow the operators to return reference-to-derived instead of reference-to-base.

Comment: @BenVoigt - That's a possibility. I did say "vaguely".  I know the solution is very likely not ready for prime time, but I don't want to think about it any more tonight.

Comment: @BenVoigt DIdit.

Comment: I would probably declare the conversion operator explicit (or remove it). You can also `= default` the assignment operator. If your class has an assignment operator, you should also implement a copy constructor.

Comment: @Jen - Tell the OP. He wrote that part.  But OK.

Comment: @Jen - Have another go at it. It won't compile now.

Comment: Can't you have the mix-in hold the actual value, and the pretender class not hold anything? It seems like the reference is kind of redundant.

Comment: @einpoklum - You would have to ask the OP that question. Probably not.

Comment: @JiveDadson Sorry, it took a second because I got messed up with the variable names.

Comment: @Jens - NP. I'm just petting dogs. They are very patient.

Comment: The OP's posted test program [does not compile with this solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589f32a4554e095c)

Comment: @MikeKinghan  Thanks for the head's up. It's fixed. It compiles and runs the test-code, including the += bit.

Comment: I declared the conversion operators explicit because IMHO implicit conversion are a great source of problems.The same is true for the constructors which should also be declared explicit, as recommended by all C++ guidelines I am aware of. Personally, I would replaced the conversion operators with a normal member function. This of course breaks the OP's code, but the result if better code quality.

Comment: @Jens I have to permit implicit conversion, that's the whole purpose of my classes. They have to behave just like the hardware registers they're pretending to be, and you have to be able to assign values of various types to them without explicit casting, otherwise the normal firmware code (which doesn't have such casting) wouldn't compile in the simulation environment. And yes, getting the right combination of constructors & `operator [typename]()` methods has been problematic and difficult, but I did manage to get it to work, thanks to Jive's and others' discussions here. CRTP is the key.

Comment: @JiveDadson - How important is `protected: ~numericCompoundAssignmentBase() {} // to prevent slicing` if the template class doesn't actually have any data members? And if it *does* have data members? (Currently the data is stored in the derived class as I have it implemented.)

Answer (score 2):

Reading @JiveJadson's answer, I was wondering - why not just have a single templated class?

```
template<typename Integer>
class register_t {
public:
    using value_type = Integer;
    register_t(Integer& val) : value_(val << 1) {}
    register_t(const register_t&) = default;
    register_t(register_t&&) = default;
    register_t& operator=(const register_t&) = default;
    register_t& operator=(register_t&&) = default;
    operator Integer() { return value_ >> 1; }

    template <typename RHSInteger>
    register_t& operator+= (const RHSInteger& rhs) {
        value_ += static_cast<Integer>(rhs) << 1; 
        return value_;
    }
private:
    Integer value_;
      // bottom bit is 0, rest of bits hold the actual value
};
```

Comment: Echoes my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49095356/1362568) "So better still just make each of them a specialization of one template"

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Somewhat true, although you have somewhat peculiar (IMHO) multiplications and divisions. Also, you use constexpr, but I think the idea is to compute everything at compile time. Also you explicitly constru from unsigned, and no other integral type.

Comment: Peculiar IMO too, but they're what the OP posts.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Oh yeah, my mind kind of ignored that part of OP's code because it didn't make sense :-P

Comment: I think the OP's classes have to do different bit-shifting and such depending on the type of register. That's why I figured one template would not fit all. @MikeKinghan

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to avoid having to define my own operator+= methods for combinations of
>   these classes because that's a lot of permutations to have to handle

But the compiler can handle them all for you. To a first approximation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

class REG16
{
private:
   uint16_t _i;
public:
   REG16() = default;
   constexpr REG16(const unsigned int i) : _i((uint16_t)i * 2) {}
   constexpr operator uint16_t() const { return _i / 2; }
   REG16& operator=(const unsigned int i) { _i = (uint16_t)i * 2; return *this; }
   template<typename T>
   REG16& operator+=(T && lhs) {
       return *this = *this + std::forward<T>(lhs); 
   }
};

class REG32
{
private:
   uint32_t _i;
public:
   REG32() = default;
   constexpr REG32(const uint32_t i) : _i(i * 2) {}
   constexpr operator uint32_t() const { return _i / 2; }
   REG32& operator=(const uint32_t i) { _i = i * 2; return *this; }
   template<typename T>
   REG32& operator+=(T && lhs) {
       return *this = *this + std::forward<T>(lhs);
   }
};
```

[Live VC++](http://rextester.com/BTIRW13471)

[Live GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd3f8131f6e8e8ca)

If you or anyone else writes code that attempts to instantiate:

```
template<typename T>
REG{16|32}& operator+=(T && lhs) {
    return *this = *this + std::forward<T>(lhs); 
}
```

with a type `T` for which:

```
*this + lhs
```

is not defined then it simply won't compile.

But this solution draws further attention to the fact that `REG16` and `REG32`
are identical modulo the type of the member `_i`. So better still just make
each of them a specialization of one template:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename IntType>
struct REG_N
{
    REG_N() = default;
    constexpr REG_N(const IntType i) 
    : _i(static_cast<IntType>(i) * 2) {}
    constexpr operator IntType() const {
       return _i / 2;
    }
    REG_N & operator=(const IntType i) { 
        _i = static_cast<IntType>(i) * 2; 
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T>
    REG_N & operator+=(T && lhs) {
       return *this = *this + std::forward<T>(lhs); 
    }
private:
   IntType _i;

};

using REG16 = REG_N<std::uint16_t>;
using REG32 = REG_N<std::uint32_t>;
```

[Live VC++](http://rextester.com/TQVTK68963)

[Live GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a26cc953e8fb5cc)

Comment: That's similar to my answer. The difference is that I proposed a mix-in class that does all the operator overloading. That way you write it once, and use it any time you need a class  to behave like a number. -- Unless you lose the code like I did. In that case you (and by "you" I mean "I") have to write it again.

Comment: @JiveDadson I don't think it is a mix-in but implementation sharing by inheritance. If you have a mix-in "AssignmentAddable" your `REG32` classes should not inherit from it. The mix-in inherits from its template parameter and thus you can compose functionality as you need it.

Comment: @Jens - I guess that's Old Speak. I pre-date many definitions. I started programming C++ in 1984, long before those patterns books came rolling off the presses. Hey, at least I called CRTP CRTP.

Comment: Why these multiplications by 2?